# What is the difference between MSOLEDBSQL vs MSOLEDBSQL.1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb

I am trying to get the difference between MSOLEDBSQL and MSOLEDBSQL.1 Can anyone please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MSOLEDBSQL` is the version independent ProgID of the COM object. This references the the latest version should multiple installed versions exist.

`MSOLEDBSQL.1` is a version-specific ProgID. This always references version 1, even if a later version is installed.

The Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server has only a single version (version 1) as of this writing so both ProgID specifications are functionally identical today. However, a general best practice with COM objects is to specify the versioned ProgID (`MSOLEDBSQL.1` here) to avoid a breaking change should a later version with different interface be installed.

Comment: When I look at the documentation, it says the following: "To use the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server in existing applications, you should plan to convert your connection strings from SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI, to MSOLEDBSQL19 or MSOLEDBSQL."
How does this compare to the MSOLEDBSQL.1 version? I could not find any reference to that version (but I see it used in many connectionstrings). It seems I can only find versions 18 to 19 in the releas notes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
Is it another ID?

Comment: @GHauan, the release notes in the link detail the enhancements since the initial `MSOLEDBSQL` version. `MSOLEDBSQL.1` is the same as `MSOLEDBSQL` since there were no subsequent ProdIDs; they changed the driver name in the later versions.